# Compile-time boolean operations for an integral_constant?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, compile-time, compile-time-constant

In the C++ standard library, are there template types that are boolean operations on `integral_constant<bool, X>` (where `X` is either `true` or `false`)?

As a simple example, you have two overloads of a function as such:

```
void foo_impl(false_type){
    cout << "false" <<endl;
}

void foo_impl(true_type){
    cout << "true" <<endl;
}
```

One of these functions is chosen by another function, based on a constant condition:

```
struct first_tag{};
struct second_tag{};
struct third_tag{};

template <typename TTag>
void foo(TTag role){
    foo_impl(typename constant_or<typename is_same<role, first_tag>::type, typename is_same<role, second_tag>::type>::type{});
}
```

In this case, the `true` version of `foo_impl()` is to be be called if the parameter to `foo()` is of type `first_tag` or `second_tag`, hence the use of a hypothetical type `constant_or`.

While it is simple to write my own version of `constant_or`, does such a type already exist in the C++ standard library?

Comment: `boost::mpl` has such functionality: `foo_impl(or_<is_same<a, b>, is_same<c, d>>{});`, with the respective boost types works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets fix your typo

```
template <typename TTag>
void foo(TTag){
    foo_impl(typename constant_or<typename is_same<TTag, first_tag>::type, typename is_same<TTag, second_tag>::type>::type{});
}
```

`is_same` acts on *types* not values.

Then lets point out you can just use the value in `is_same`.

```
template <typename TTag>
void foo(TTag){
    foo_impl(integral_constant<bool, is_same_v<TTag, first_tag> | is_same_v<TTag, second_tag>>{});
}
```

And you're done. Saves a lot of typing too, which is always a plus.

On the note of saving typing (because god forbid)

```
template<bool B>
using bool_constant = integral_constant<bool, B>;
```

is defined by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

It is called `std::conditional`. Similar metafunctions, conjunction, disjunction, negation are also coming in C++17.